# How to get column names from custom TextClause query in SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an app that typically takes a SQL Alchemy `selectable` as an input and uses `reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine).get_columns(selectable.name, schema=selectable.schema)` to get the columns for additional downstream logic.

This app also allows the user to pass a custom `TextClause` query as an input. Is it possible to reverse engineer the column names from the `TextClause` as is done with the `selectable` object?

What have I tried?

```
>>> import sqlalchemy as sa
>>> query = "SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM table"
>>> selectable = sa.text(query)

# The steps above cannot be altered

>>> type(selectable)
<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause'>
>>> connection_string = "postgresql+psycopg2://<user>:<password>@localhost:5432/<db>"
>>> engine = sa.create_engine(connection_string)
>>> columns = sa.engine.reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine).get_columns(selectable, schema=None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py", line 498, in get_columns
    conn, table_name, schema, info_cache=self.info_cache, **kw
  File "<string>", line 2, in get_columns
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py", line 55, in cache
    ret = fn(self, con, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py", line 3578, in get_columns
    connection, table_name, schema, info_cache=kw.get("info_cache")
  File "<string>", line 2, in get_table_oid
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py", line 55, in cache
    ret = fn(self, con, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py", line 3457, in get_table_oid
    raise exc.NoSuchTableError(table_name)
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError: SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM table
```